# why quartz scheduleJob() execute many times?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

```
public class QuartzStudy implements Job {
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
    System.out.println(jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getKey().getName() + "-" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "-" + new Date());
}

private static SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
private static Scheduler scheduler;
static {
    try {
        scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException, InterruptedException {
    JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzStudy.class).withIdentity("job1").build();
    CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("*/5 * * * * ?").withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
            .build();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    scheduler.pauseJob(jobDetail.getKey());
}
```

}

This code should console twice and then pause?

But sometimes console three times,why?

job1-DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1-14-Thu Jan 03 09:34:45 CST 2019

job1-DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2-15-Thu Jan 03 09:34:50 CST 2019

job1-DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3-16-Thu Jan 03 09:34:55 CST 2019

Comment: Can you try putting `scheduler.start();` after `scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);`? Please share your response.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `*/5 * * * * ?` means `Every 5 seconds starting at :00 second after the minute`.

You are doing `Thread.sleep(10000);`. This means `main thread` will be paused for 10 seconds. But, since you are getting logs even in those 10 seconds, that means scheduler is independent of `main thread`. So, at 10th second, scheduler will create a thread to run `execute` and also after 10th second, you are pausing `job`.If first one(i.e. creating of thread occurs before `pausing`) occurs first, logs will be printed thrice. Whereas if second one(`pausing` of `job` occurs before `spawning` new thread) occurs first, logs will be printed only twice. That's why sometime log is getting printed twice and sometimes thrice.

So, to be sure that logs are printed only twice, decrease sleep time to 9 seconds. I tried below code and it always prints logs twice:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Main method:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzStudy.class).withIdentity("job1").build();
        CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("*/5 * * * * ?").withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
                .build();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
        scheduler.start();    // it's better to start job once you have scheduled one
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        scheduler.pauseJob(jobDetail.getKey());
        System.out.println("Job is Paused!!!");
    }
```

Comment: i know your means, i solve this problem  but  i  find scheduler.resumeJob()   it execute twice   how to solve it?

Comment: `scheduler.resumeJob()` is no where in question. Can you explain it more clearly... maybe by providing expected input and output. Where exactly are you placing `resumeJob`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54015360/why-quartz-schedulejob-execute-many-times/54020548#54020548